# Invalid ID for offset-based ZoneId - Java 8

Tags: java, tomcat, java-8, tomcat8

I am using the LocalDate and LocalDateTime API. In my machine (Windows) it works normally, however when I start the service on a Linux server the error occurs: Invalid ID for offset-based ZoneId: GMT-3: 00

Already configure the server Locale to pt_BR and timezone to America / Sao_Paulo and the error persists.

I tried configuring Tomcat by inserting configuration parameters into the setenv.sh file and also did not succeed.

**Controller**

```
 @RestController
    public class HomeController {


        @RequestMapping("/zone-id-default")
        public ZoneId zoneIdDefault() {
            return ZoneId.systemDefault();
        }

    }
```

**StackTrace**

```
    java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid ID for offset-based ZoneId: GMT-3:00
        at java.time.ZoneId.ofWithPrefix(ZoneId.java:437)
        at java.time.ZoneId.of(ZoneId.java:407)
        at java.time.ZoneId.of(ZoneId.java:359)
        at java.time.ZoneId.of(ZoneId.java:315)
        at java.util.TimeZone.toZoneId(TimeZone.java:556)
        at java.time.ZoneId.systemDefault(ZoneId.java:274)
        at br.coop.unimedgoiania.controller.HomeController.zoneIdDefault(HomeController.java:27)
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid ID for ZoneOffset, non numeric characters found: -3:00
    at java.time.ZoneOffset.parseNumber(ZoneOffset.java:269)
    at java.time.ZoneOffset.of(ZoneOffset.java:221)
    at java.time.ZoneId.ofWithPrefix(ZoneId.java:431)
```

**JVM Arguments passed by catalina.sh**

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-Duser.timezone=America/Sao_Paulo"
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with these api? Tomcat should not give any error for just using this api. Can you please show your code?

Comment: a simple LocalDate.now() occurs the error

Comment: Any stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this. I think the below code should resolve the issue.

```
 @RequestMapping("/zone-id-default")
        public ZoneId zoneIdDefault() {
            return ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo");
        }
```

**Reg the LocalDate:-**

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"));
```

**Best Practice:-**

The best practice to get the LocalDate is:-

```
LocalDate.now(Clock.system(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo")));
```

**From Java Doc:-**

> Best practice for applications is to pass a Clock into any method that
>   requires the current instant. A dependency injection framework is one
>   way to achieve this:

```
public class MyBean {
    private Clock clock;  // dependency inject
    ...
    public void process(LocalDate eventDate) {
      if (eventDate.isBefore(LocalDate.now(clock)) {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
```

[Clock class with the above best practice information](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html)